# how to open anoter activity if click on notification?

Tags: android

```
 public class SimpleService extends Service {
 private NotificationManager mNM;
 private int NOTIFICATION = 0;

 public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        SimpleService getService() {
            return SimpleService.this;
        }
    }
 @Override
 public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return mBinder;
 }

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Toast.makeText(this,"Service created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();        
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // Cancel the persistent notification.
    mNM.cancel(NOTIFICATION);
    // Tell the user we stopped.
    Toast.makeText(this,"Service is destroy", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}   

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    super.onCreate();
    Toast.makeText(this,"Service started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Toast.makeText(this,"task perform in service",300).show();
    mNM = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // Display a notification about us starting.  We put an icon in the status bar.
    showNotification();
    return START_STICKY;
}   

  // This is the object that receives interactions from clients.  See
    // RemoteService for a more complete example.
    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

    /**
     * Show a notification while this service is running.
     */
    private void showNotification() {
        // In this sample, we'll use the same text for the ticker and the expanded notification
        CharSequence text = getText(R.string.local_service_started);

        // Set the icon, scrolling text and timestamp
        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, text,
                System.currentTimeMillis());
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,NotificationRecieverActivity.class);
        // The PendingIntent to launch our activity if the user selects this notification
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,intent, 0);

        // Set the info for the views that show in the notification panel.
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, "latest information",
                       text, contentIntent);

        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        // Send the notification.
        mNM.notify(NOTIFICATION, notification);
    }
```

}

If I am click on notification then this notification is clear but I wont to show this notification message to another activity i.e NotificationRecieverActivity.class but this not display anything. Please help me.

Comment: You should read the manual on this, it's not always as linear as the simple answers that have been provided (e.g. you may want to provide back navigation to maintain the application experience)

    http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Answer (score 3):

Do the following

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this,NotificationRecieverActivity.class);
 intent.putExtra("YOURTAG", "DATA");
    // The PendingIntent to launch our activity if the user selects this notification
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,intent, 0);
```

OR Using bundle

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,NotificationRecieverActivity.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("YOURTAG", "DATA");
intent.putExtra("BUNDLETAG", bundle);
// The PendingIntent to launch our activity if the user selects this notification
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,intent, 0);
```

Full Class

```
public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {
private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;

public GcmIntentService() {
    super("GcmIntentService");
}
public static final String TAG = "Mobien Reception Service";

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
    // The getMessageType() intent parameter must be the intent you received
    // in your BroadcastReceiver.
    String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

    if (!extras.isEmpty()) {  // has effect of unparcelling Bundle
        /*
         * Filter messages based on message type. Since it is likely that GCM will be
         * extended in the future with new message types, just ignore any message types you're
         * not interested in, or that you don't recognize.
         */
        if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
            makeMessage("Send error: " + extras.toString());
        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
            makeMessage("Deleted messages on server: " + extras.toString());
        // If it's a regular GCM message, do some work.
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Received Message :"+extras.getString("message"));
            makeMessage(extras.getString("message"));
        }
    }
    // Release the wake lock provided by the WakefulBroadcastReceiver.
    GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}

private void makeMessage(String msg) {

    if(!msg.equals("") || msg.contains("#")) {
        String temp [] = StringUtility.split(msg, '#');
        String header = temp[0];
        Log.d(TAG, "Header Message :"+header);
        if(header.trim().contains("DLV")) {
            sendNotification("Del. No. "+temp[1], "Against SAP SO.No. "+temp[2], 123);
        } else if(header.trim().contains("PGI")) {
            sendNotification("PGI No. "+temp[1], "Against Del. No."+temp[2], 99);
        } else if(header.trim().contains("INV")) {
            sendNotification("Inv. No. "+temp[1], "Against Del. No."+temp[2], 157);
        }
    }
}

// Put the message into a notification and post it.
// This is just one simple example of what you might choose to do with
// a GCM message. 
private void sendNotification(String contentTitle, String contentText) {

    final Random r = new Random();
    final int notificationId = r.nextInt();

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class), 0);

    Bitmap largeIcon= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(), 
            R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
    .setContentTitle(contentTitle)
    .setContentText(contentText)
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(), 0));


    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(notificationId, mBuilder.build());
}
```

Its something I had made for my demo. I don't have time to modify according to your needs. But it should help you out in what you are doing.

Comment: I am write this code but exception is occure - 07-12 16:56:34.450: E/AndroidRuntime(1932): java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Unable to start service com.bogotobogo.serviceprovider.SimpleService@41554238 with Intent { cmp=com.bogotobogo.serviceprovider/.SimpleService }:
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
 contentView required: pkg=com.bogotobogo.serviceprovider id=0 notification=Notification(pri=0 contentView=null vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0x0 kind=[null])

Comment: According to what you are doing here you really dont need a class which extends service. Use IntentService instead.

Updating the answer with a service which creates a notification with an intent call.

Comment: I wont show notification if app is not running state on device.If any updatat in app to show update to user via notification

Comment: I am sorry I didn't understand what you want to say! You only want to show notification if app is in foreground? Makes no sense actually. If this is what you want to say. Cause the use of notifications is to notify user even when he is not in your app. Please explain more and in a descriptive manner for all of us to help you more.

Comment: sir, If my application is not opend on android mobile but background processing is start if user in network connection(wifi...) .How to create service method in android then this service method to check any time to server if any changes to app then display to notification on user mobile.If any changes if i wont to show news to user If to new news updated to server then this news show to user vi a notifaction.....please help me .I dont now to service method related.

Comment: According to my minuscule understanding of the English language and my astonishingly bad interpretation skills, what i could come up with what you are asking has a solution over here -http://commonsware.com/blog/2010/08/11/activity-notification-ordered-broadcast.html

Answer (score 0):

Try by intent something like below

```
Intent a=new Intent(this,NewActivity.class);
a.putExtra("var", "your message"); //value passing
startActivity(a);
```

And get the message in NewActivity class such as

```
try {
     Intent i = getIntent();            
     String message = i.getStringExtra("var");          
}catch (Exception ex) {
    Log.e("Error", "Loading exception");
}
```

Comment: I am write this code but exception is occure . 07-12 16:41:33.460: E/AndroidRuntime(1753): java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Unable to start service com.bogotobogo.serviceprovider.SimpleService@41554278 with Intent { cmp=com.bogotobogo.serviceprovider/.SimpleService }:
 android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: 
Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?

Comment: did u change your Activity class name?

Comment: Use intent in activity class and SimpleService class by creating object!!

Answer (score 0):

Just add the pending intent you created, to the notification as -

```
notification.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
```

after creation of PendingIntent.

Comment: Setcontentintent();this method is not availabel . but i am set  ---notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, "latest information",
                         text, contentIntent);
method.

Comment: `Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, text,
                System.currentTimeMillis());` As this method is deprecated it is better to use NotificationBuilder to create notification.

Comment: Here is an example of creating notification using NotificationBuilder `NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
    notificationBuilder.setTicker("Ticker Text");
 notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
 notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
 notificationBuilder.setContentTitle("content title").setContentText("content text").setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
 mNm.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.build());`